# When will the first Generalist badges be awarded?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges

According to the [Generalist Badge Implemented](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/) blog post,

> there must be at least 200 questions in all 40 of the top tags before this badge is awarded to anyone.

Right now, our "tag no. 40" (margins) features [exactly 200 questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags?page=2&tab=popular). IIRC, the tag has hit the limit yesterday, sometime in the afternoon. I had expected that the first Generalist badges would be awarded either immediately or in the morning of the next day (today). But no user has been awarded a Generalist badge so far. When can we expect our shiny new badges?

(Just in case anyone asks: I guess there should be at least a dozen "instant awards". I'm no. 5 rep-wise at the moment, and have a total score of >=15 in 31 of the top 40 tags.)

Comment: I like how with this question the OP earned a 'Nice Question' badge without getting any answer... and no 'Generalist' badge either...

Comment: Could a delay be caused by tag synonyms?

Comment: @Werner: Clever thinking, though this would seem to be a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have another explanation: [My Generalist badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep?tab=activity#lockstep?tab=activity&sort=badges&_suid=132274702053305403856299171188) was awarded 17 seconds after the [*201st*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36797/how-can-i-make-todonotes-use-all-of-the-margin) [margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/margins) question had been asked.

Comment: So it seems like "at least" should be interpreted with a little more flexibility. Another example of this is contained within the abbreviated description for the [Populist Gold Badge](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist): "Answer outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x". From the [ultimate list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) this actually means an outscored answer worth (at least) **23** upvotes compared to (at least) **11** of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

It just got assigned to 26 people. Apparently there was some delay in the script. It possibly only runs once a day.